# Different functions different delays c#

Tags: c#, winforms, delay

I'm making a simple c# game similar to snake, and I have two moving aspects. I have a method to move both of them, however I want them to both move at different speeds. Here's a cut down version of the method I have now.

```
private async void mover()
{
    while (GlobalVar.Status == "alive")
    {
         if (GlobalVar.Direction == "up")
         {
              try { moveupp(GlobalVar.Row, GlobalVar.Column, "player"); }
              catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException) { died(); }
         }
         if (GlobalVar.OppDirection == "up")
         {
              try { moveupp(GlobalVar.Row, GlobalVar.Column, "opp1"); }
              catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException) { died(); }
         }
         await Task.Delay(500);
   }
}
```

Here, in the first IF statement, my character (player) is moving up, and in the second IF statement, the opponent (opp1) is moving up. These are working in sync with a 500 millisecond delay in between with the delay "await Task.Delay(500);". 
My question is, is there anyway they can both run together, with different delays in between? So the opp1 can move faster than the player?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use exceptions to control program flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two different timers instead of delaying tasks. Also I would not use exceptions to control program flow:

```
private PlayerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (GlobalVar.Status != "alive")
         return; // you can also stop timer in this case

     if (GlobalVar.Direction == "up")
     {
         if (GlobalVar.Column == 0)
             died();
         else
             moveupp(GlobalVar.Row, GlobalVar.Column, "player");  
     }
}
```

Also create timer for `opp1` and set different intervals for these timers - 500 for player and  another value for opp1.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense. I'm sorry for the simple questions, but how can I invoke this method, and how do I use a timer?

Comment: @LucasHolmes that depends on type of your application - is it Winforms application?

Comment: @LucasHolmes then it's simple. You can find `Timer` component in Toolbox. Add two timers to your form, then subscribe to their `Tick` event (that will add event handlers as one above). And last step is setting `Interval` property of timers (you can do it from designer of from code) and start them by calling `Start()` method when game starts.